# IErrorInfo.GetDescription com E_FAIL(0x80004005) IMPORTING EXCEL FILES

Tags: c#, html, sql, asp.net, excel

Whenever I import data from an Excel file that is inside the IIS Express folder, everything goes fine without errors, and the Excel file goes to the table that I create in SQL, but when the Excel file is in another place, it gives that error... Why?

Here's my code:

```
protected void Upload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string excelPath = Server.MapPath("~/Files/") + Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
    FileUpload1.SaveAs(excelPath);

    string filepath = FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName;
    string filename = Path.GetFileName(filepath);

    string ext = Path.GetExtension(filename);
    String strConnection = @"Data Source=PEDRO-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=costumizado;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=1234";
    string excelConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + filepath + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HRD=YES;IMEX=1;\"";

    OleDbConnection excelConnection = new OleDbConnection(excelConnectionString);

    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("Select [Nome],[Cidade],[Idade] from [Folha1$]", excelConnection);

    excelConnection.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();


    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select [Nome],[Cidade],[Idade] from [Folha1$]", strConnection);

    OleDbDataReader dReader;
    dReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    SqlBulkCopy sqlBulk = new SqlBulkCopy(strConnection);

    sqlBulk.DestinationTableName = "Teste";
    sqlBulk.WriteToServer(dReader);
    excelConnection.Close();

}
```

The error is on line:

```
 excelConnection.Open();
```

Comment: A website does not have permission to do stuff outside it's root folder. You could enable it but that is NOT recommended.

Comment: So  How can I import my excel file by an random folder like: desktop or a created folder? It should be possibel importing an excel file in whenever he is... @VDWWD Any ideia how to do it?

Comment: You don't. If you want to import through a website better use a fileupload or put it in a specific folder in the website. Unless you want to give an AppPool much more permissions.

Comment: @VDWWD I'm using a fileupload, and I created a folder in my project named "Files"... How I say to my web site to store in that folder and after that upload to sql? is there a way?